# How do I send the output of a command that has two steps to a file?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to use Python 2.7 on a linux terminal to send the output of a command to a text file.

The command has two steps:

`impu.sh` and `1`.

Basically, I send `impu.sh` to the server and it prompts me to enter either `1` or `2`.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess

file = open("/home/jperez_scripts/pre_upg.txt" , "w")

subprocess.Popen(["impu.sh","1"] , stdout=file)
```

Comment: Hi, what is exactly the problem you see?

Comment: Sorry. New to this.  Forgot to paste the error.  Don't have access at the moment , but it was an erno file not found error.

Comment: Which one? The `impu.sh` file? Have you tried specifying the full path of it?

Comment: Impu.sh output is has an input statement requiring either 1 or 2. For my purposes, I need 2.  Basically, it provides the number of callers on a server.

Comment: I figured it out based on a little trial and error.  Here is what worked: